# How do I know which view is associated with which controller?

Tags: ember.js

Say I have this piece of code:

```
App.ClickableView = Ember.View.extend({
  click: function(evt) {
    this.get('controller').send('turnItUp', 11); 
  }
});
```

When I do `this.get('controller')` inside the view, how do I know exactly which controller I'm getting?  Is there a way to bind a view to a specific controller, such that `this.get('controller')` returns that controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I do this.get('controller') inside the view, how do I know exactly which controller I'm getting?

```
console.log(this.get('controller').toString());
```

> Is there a way to bind a view to a specific controller, such that this.get('controller') returns that controller?

Yes and no. Yes because `controller` is a property so can be set like anything else. But no because it's probably not a good idea unless you really know what you are doing. Just be sure you are using the appropriate helper - see this post for an overview of the options:

http://darthdeus.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/render-control-partial-view/

Typically ember will take care of setting a view's controller property to the appropriate controller. So in most cases the view should not care what controller it's working with. Add whatever logic or properties that are required to that controller. If the controller requires access to data or logic from another controller, use controller's needs property enable cross-controller communication.